# Spring cloud port number, making the choice intelligent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm running a Spring Cloud with Eureka server, and I would like to make my application choose a port based on used ports and a range given.

For example, I want my first instance to start at port 8010, the second at 8011 etc.

In application.properties you can set a random port (`server.port=0`), you can set a static port (`server.port=8080`) but I want to know how I can make spring set a random port in a range, or pick a port based on used ports.

For example, something like this would work:

```
server.port.random=8080-8090
```

But that obviously does not exist.

I also know there can be added some logic, for example I've used:

```
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${random.int}
```

But I don't know how I can make that random work between two numbers. Also there is still a chance that the random will set the same port twice in a row, making the server failing to start the instance.

Is there a way to set a port dynamically in Spring application.properties?

Comment: I'd imagine you're having this issue because you're trying to run these projects locally and having collisions when running multiple versions of the same app. Would overwriting SERVER_PORT or (server.port) as an environment variable get the desired effect?

java -jar app.jar --SERVER_PORT=8080;

java -jar app.jar --SERVER_PORT=8081

Comment: @shinjw Good idea, and you made me think in another direction. I thought this was going to be a production issue as well, but then on production servers you can obviously run the same port on multiple IP's. I think I can work with the overwrite for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to specify a random port in a given range. In your properties file.

`server.port=${random.int[8080,8090]}`

There is still a possibility for collision, but if you have enough padding for the range, you can limit the chances of that happening.

The more preferred approach, however, would be to specify the port as an environment variables.

`java -jar app.jar --SERVER_PORT=8080`

`java -jar app.jar --SERVER_PORT=8081`

Answer (score 1):

If you determine the port number with `server.port=${random.int[8080,8090]}`, you may encounter an issue which this number was already in use.
Another choice is to specify the port number randomly by program, which will always return an available number based on the range you specified.
For example:

**application.properties**

```
port.number.min=8080
port.number.max=8090
```

**Partial code in your main class**

```
@Value("${port.number.min:8080}")
private Integer minPortNum = 8080;

@Value("${port.number.max:8090}")
private Integer maxPortNum = 8090;

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {             
            int port = SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(minPortNum, maxPortNum);                
            container.setPort(port);
            System.getProperties().put("server.port", port);
        }
    };
}
```